# How to explode a string in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Given a string value, how do you iterate over every character in Thymeleaf?

The `#strings.arraySplit` and related methods don't work because they use `StringTokenkizer`, which doesn't support zero-width separators.

```xml
<p>Characters in <span th:text="${myString}"/>:</p>
<ul><li th:each="char : ${...}" th:text="${char}"/></ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the docs you can iterate arrays as well with th:each.
One option would be:

```
<ul><li th:each="char : ${mystring.toCharArray()}" th:text="${char}"/></ul>
```

More info here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values

**EDIT:**
After doing a small test I found out that *char* is a **Character** wrapper object. I tested it with this:

```
<ul><li th:each="char : ${myString.toCharArray()}" th:text="'Is it a char primitive:' + ${char instanceof T(char)}"/></ul>
<ul><li th:each="char : ${myString.toCharArray()}" th:text="'Is it a Character wrapper:' + ${char instanceof T(Character)}"/></ul>
```

Comment: Iterating an array wasn't the problem, it was getting an array. Is the `char` variable going to be a `char`, a `Character` or a `String`?